# Error assigning random rank using random() and row_number in R

Tags: r, function, random, compiler-errors

I am trying to replicate the analysis made here [Three Strategies for Working with Big Data in R](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/07/17/3-big-data-strategies-for-r/), chunk-by-chunk.
When i get to the part of sampling the data, i type

```
df_mod <- df %>% group_by(is_delayed) %>% mutate(x = random() %>% row_number()) %>% ungroup()
```

and as result i get the error :

Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `x = random() %>% row_number()`.
i In group 1: `is_delayed = FALSE`.
Caused by error in `random()`:
! could not find function "random"

Is the random function part of an external package? I did load the library suggested by the article author with no success.

I would be glad to receive any insights of yo all.

Thank you!

As described above, the code returns an error that i have not yet experienced.

Comment: is your `df` a `data.frame` or a table-connection when connecting to a postgres database?

Comment: That link you provided says in a comment `Assign random rank (using random and row_number from postgres)`, which means that the `random() %>% row_number()` is really calling two _postgres_ functions that look like they might be in R. However, when in a lazy-pipeline such as starting with `df <- tbl(db, "flights")`, it is not always that simple. Try instead `df %>% group_by(is_delayed) %>% mutate(rank = sample(row_number()))`, it might work.

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans, it did work! As for the df, i did directly load the flights data set from nycflights13 package in rstudio, since i am not yet familiar with the process of accessing the database using DBI package.